# The equations $y''+p_1(x)y'+q_1(x)y=0$ and $y''+p_2(x)y'+q_2(x)y=0$ have the same solution on $(a,b)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $_1,p_2,q_1$ and $q_2$ are continuous on $(a,b)$and the  The equations $y''+p_1(x)y'+q_1(x)y=0$ and $y''+p_2(x)y'+q_2(x)y=0$ have the same solution on $(a,b)$ then $p_1=p_2$ and $q_1=q_2$

*What i am tried*

I am using trying prove this by Able's formula

for first equation $W[y_1,y_2](x)=c_1 e^{-\int p_1(x)dx}$

and for second equation  $W[y_1,y_2](x)=c_2 e^{-\int p_2(x)dx}$

Since he equations $y''+p_1(x)y'+q_1(x)y=0$ and $y''+p_2(x)y'+q_2(x)y=0$ have the same solution on $(a,b)$

is it $W[y_1,y_2](x)=W[y_1,y_2](x) \Rightarrow p_1(x)=p_2(x)$ is i am coorect

Comment: Why not look at the difference of the two equations?

Comment: @Mattos..yes this is simply coolll.... I did't get that  you are amazing

Comment: @Mattos..i am trying that i did't get

Comment: @Mattos..difference work after i show $p_1=p_2$

Comment: $y = 0$ is indeed a common solution.

Comment: just to add to what Alex Francisco has said, $y\equiv 0$ is a solution to both, even if $p_1\neq p_2$.  As such, just knowing the two equations have the same solution on an interval does not guarantee the conclusion.

Comment: Let  $ p_1(x)-p_2(x)= p(x), ... = q(x) $  Solve the differential equation $y'p(x) + q(x)  y =0 $ to get full non-trivial  picture.

Comment: For an answer to an essentially the same question, see [Comparing two Differential equations which have a same solution set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3165540/comparing-two-differential-equations-which-have-a-same-solution-set/3165609#3165609).