# Comparing two Differential equations which have a same solution set.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$P(x)y''+Q(x)y'+R(x)y=0$$ $$P_1(x)y''+Q_1(x)y'+R_1(x)y=0$$

Suppose above two differential equations have a same solution set, then does it true that it must imply conditions $$P(x)=kP_1(x) , Q(x)=kQ_1(x) , R(x)=kR_1(x) \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \text{for some $k(x,y)$}$$ ??

($y''= \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} ,y'= \frac{dy}{dx}$ )

If this is true, then how can i prove this?

Comment: If the function $y(x) = k$ where $k$ is a constant. Then obviously the conditions for $P(x),P_1(x)$ and $Q(x),Q_1(x)$ need not b true. In fact, if $y(x) = 0$, then all conditions fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you tacitly assume that $P, Q, R \colon I \to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous and that $P(x) \ne 0$ for all $x \in I$.  Then the problem reduces to showing that for the linear homogeneous second order ODE
$$
\tag{1}
y''(x) - \tilde{Q}(x) y'(x) - \tilde{R}(x) y(x) = 0
$$
if we know the solution set (or, what is equivalent, if we know a fundamental system of solutions) then the coefficients $\tilde{Q}(\cdot)$ and $\tilde{R}(\cdot)$ can be uniquely determined.

Indeed, let $(y_1(\cdot), y_2(\cdot))$ be a fundamental system of solutions of $(1)$. Then for each $x \in I$ there holds
$$
\tag{2}
\begin{cases}
y'_1(x) \tilde{Q}(x) + y_1(x) \tilde{R}(x) = y''_1(x)
\\
y'_2(x) \tilde{Q}(x) + y_2(x) \tilde{R}(x) = y''_2(x).
\end{cases}
$$
As $(y_1(\cdot), y_2(\cdot))$ is a fundamental system of solutions, for each $x \in I$ its Wrońskian is nonzero, so $(2)$ is a Cramer system in unknowns $\tilde{Q}(x)$ and $\tilde{R}(x)$.

Comment: Thank you , I understand obviously!